# Smartface 4.5 ios admob

Tags: ios, admob, smartface.io

I have followed the guidelines in the below code to display admob. But, it does not display and gives error:

```
"Request Error:Invalid ad request parameter..."
```

Is something wrong in the below code?
Is there any working code for admob?

```
var adView = new SMFBannerView({
       top : '90%',
       left :'0%',
        animated : true
       } );
adView.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-2822097230699730/896839XXXX");
adView.setAdSizeIndex(0);
Pages.Page1.add(adView);
adView.updateRootController();
var request = GADRequest.request();
request.testDevices = [adView.simulatorId()];
adView.loadRequest(request);
var adViewDelegate = new SMFBannerViewDelegate();
adViewDelegate.onSuccess = function (e) {
alert("Ad loaded.");
};
adViewDelegate.onError = function (e) {
alert(e);
};
adView.setDelegate(adViewDelegate);
```

Comment: Smartface 4.5 also doesn't open it's emulator on android devices a big bug. Dd you receive this bug?

Comment: my smartface opens android smilator with genymotion

Comment: Are you trying it on iOS emulator? Plugins only work with publish not emulator.

Comment: i am trying to publish not using emulator and i get this error from xcode! i tried many options with code but not succesfull. Seems that something wrong with plugin again or something wrong with gudie that officially published! i will be very happy if you put some working code to be sure that my code is not correct!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
// SMFBannerView
var adView = new SMFBannerView();
adView.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-yourAdID");

// SMFBannerViewDelegate
var adViewDelegate = new SMFBannerViewDelegate();
adViewDelegate.onSuccess = function (e) {
    alert("Ad loaded.");
};
adViewDelegate.onError = function (e) {
    alert(e);
};
adView.setDelegate(adViewDelegate);

// Button to trigger
var btn = new SMF.UI.TextButton();
btn.onPressed = function (e) {
    adView.setAdSizeIndex(1);
    adView.updateRootController();

    var request = GADRequest.request();
    request.testDevices = [adView.simulatorId()];
    adView.loadRequest(request);
};
Pages.Page1.add(adView);
Pages.Page1.add(btn);
```

Your problem will be because you are directly calling admob. Try to use this code block. It works fine for me.
Also, keep in mind that, you must call loadRequest method after onShow of page is finished.

Comment: How to set the position of the adView?

Comment: You can use adView.top = "%90"; after var adView = new SMFBannerView();